# Extending Spark TextInput to auto-resize

Tags: actionscript-3, components, flex4

Hi have a Spark TextInput control but I haven't figured out a way to make is auto-resize...Does anyone have any code to get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no code, but I guess it shouldn't be too hard. you should simply [watch changes](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableTextBase.html#event:change), and then grab the new text size. I don't have flex 4 right now, but I guess you should take a peek into the sources and try to drill to the used TLF-components to get the size.